# what does the truststoreFile parameter in the tomcat-maven-plugin mean/do?

Tags: maven, tomcat, ssl

I'm trying to use the tomcat[7]-maven-plugin to deploy my war to my tomcat instance.  However, it's running over https with a self-signed cert.  So, I'd like to import the cert into a truststore in order to deploy it.  I thought the [truststoreFile](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#truststoreFile) parameter might let me specify the custom truststore I'd like to use for the action, but it doesn't seem to.  Can anyone tell me what it does?

Answer (score 0):

Truststore in this context is used to validate certificates provided by the **clients** to the server (lookup SSL client certificate). I'm not too familiar with tomcat but I would imagine that the parameter is used to point to a custom truststore (which could contain custom trusted certificates or CA's) Server's own certificates, self-signed or not, go to a keystore.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The more I work with the plugin, the more I'm thinking this is only going to be used for running an embedded container rather than for performing deployments.